# Difference in behaviour of identical lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

When attempting [N-Queens](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens/), the solution I was using would break when using the first way to create a list.

I thought both of these methods created the same list, why do they behave differently?

(Full Code Below)

Final Output (incorrect):

```
board = [["."]*n]*n
# [["QQQQ","QQQQ","QQQQ","QQQQ"],["QQQQ","QQQQ","QQQQ","QQQQ"]]
```

Final output (correct):

```
board = [["."]*n for i in range(n)]
# [[".Q..","...Q","Q...","..Q."],["..Q.","Q...","...Q",".Q.."]]
```

```py
class Solution:
  def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
    out = [] 
    cols = set()
    pos_diag = set()
    neg_diag = set()
    # board = [["."]*n]*n
    board = [["."]*n for i in range(n)]
    def dfs(r):
      if r == n:
        copy = ["".join(row) for row in board]
        out.append(copy)
        return
      for c in range(n):
        if c in cols or (r+c) in pos_diag or (r-c) in neg_diag:
          continue
        cols.add(c)
        pos_diag.add(r+c)
        neg_diag.add(r-c)
        board[r][c] = "Q"
        dfs(r+1)
        cols.remove(c)
        pos_diag.remove(r+c)
        neg_diag.remove(r-c)
        board[r][c] = "."
    dfs(0)
    return out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing a list with `[["."]*n]*n` will create a list of n references to a *single* list of length n.

If you want to construct n separate lists, then you will need to do that using some kind of iteration. In your example this is achieved using a list comprehension (which is the canonical way of doing it).

The reason for this is that `[x]*n` creates a list containing `n` *references* to `x`. When `x` is immutable (e.g. a string) you don't really notice an issue, since the only operation you can perform on that reference would be to delete it or overwrite it with something new. However, you should always be cautious when `x` can be mutable (e.g. another list).